# Execute PHP User Function within mySQL Query Result

Tags: php, mysql, eval, preg-replace-callback

For a site content creators maintain HTML lists in the format below which a cronjob (Perl) parses into a mySQL database. PHP pulls the data into paginated indices.

```
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
<a href="../path/to/file.php">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a><br>
consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
```

(Perl extracts text and URL and stores them in the database as header, URL, linktext, footer.)

Occasionally a user function call is inserted into the text, like this:

```
<li>Lorem ipsum <?php age(1234) ?> dolor sit amet<br>
<a href="../path/to/file.php">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a><br>
consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
```

The query returns this string for the first line ($header):

```
'Lorem ipsum <?php age(1234) ?> dolor sit amet'
```

Of course this is not executed when pulled in a query. Nor would it occur in a fixed place, thus cannot be parsed into a separate field.

I have read a couple threads on using `eval` here, and given that only content creators in the house edit the lists, it should be safe enough. IOW if evil code is injected in either list or database we have bigger problems than unsanitized code inserted by some outside party into a form.

My other idea is `preg_replace_callback()`. However, some suggested on SO that essentially it has the same problem as `eval`, albeit I think the regex should/could lock this down. Also I don't see how this could execute arbitrary code, unless by passing it as parameter value to the user function.

What would be the better approach? Or is there some other, safer approach? (PHP 7.2, mySQL 5.6)

TIA

**Edit**

I have implemented the code below using a callback, and no `eval`. Applying only to few permitted functions which incidentally all require only one numerical parameter it seems quite locked down.

```
if (stristr($header, '<?php ') !== FALSE) {
    $header = preg_replace_callback(
        '/<\?php (?P<php>(?P<func>(function|whitelist))?\((?P<value>\d+)\)) \?\>/i',
        function($matches) {
//          print_r($matches);
            ob_start();                                // functions print, not return
//          $matches['php'];                           // does not work
            $matches['func']($matches['value']);       // works
//          call_user_func($matches[1], $matches[2]);  // unnecessary detour
//          $out = ob_get_clean();                     // ditto
//          return $out;
            return ob_get_clean();
        },
        $header
    );
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The reason you don't call `eval` is because it allows people to escalate their privileges. Getting access to your content management system one thing, they can get a lot of data that way, but it's not nearly as severe a compromise as being able to run arbitrary code with no limitations. How would `<?php ... ?>` type code show up here in the first place?

Comment: You need a way of parsing the string, and then have a list of functions you allow ppl to use.  Then you build the code from the input, not from running the input.  [For Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c4791f1c49e3bff0c1fb004ceb08ad27a5da735) it's not a small thing to do.

Comment: @tadman see edit for clarified example with user function call inserted in HTML pls.

Comment: @tadman Yes, but since this database is fed by in-house content production, not by any user input, the attacker would have to be in-house, too.  That's what I mean with "bigger problem".

Comment: What I'm specifically saying is a fault in your software which allows access to editing content, bypassing one layer of security, could be escalated into a complete compromise if `eval` is used here. The attacker doesn't have to be in-house. They just have to have in-house credentials, and we all know people are *terrible* at assigning passwords. Additionally this opens you up to a simple CSRF attack escalating into a full system compromise.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Tks for the suggest of a whitelist and the code sample (which incidentally reminded of the usefulness of named matches). The PHP tags are as good a token for parsing as any other and besides allow the editors to check their stuff locally before the cron picks up the committed/uploaded list.

Comment: Sure if you want to write a Lexer/Parser for them I have some examples on GitHub and an empty starting one [Here](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Lexers)  They use Preg Match All, but most of the tokenization part is taken care of, you just have to put in the body of what the tokens do.  The only issue you will have is you may have trouble useing capture groups in the tokens (it's just how it works)

Comment: @tadman I'm probably dense, but I can't see how in our workflow either escalation or attack should happen. The editors write the listings locally, commit to version control, from where they are uploaded to the server. No browser involved. While you are quite right about passwords, an attacker must gain either local access or to the server, and then he could do anything anyway. That said, I'm not insisting in any way on using `eval`, on the contrary, if just for the chance that a change in the workflow could expose it in a compromising way w/o being aware of it.

Comment: I think you should use a proper templating system for introducing content to avoid this trap altogether, something like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) for example.

Comment: @tadman Tks, but I fail to see what difference such a system would make in this case, or what would you suggest for something like `On 9/11, X years ago` in copy text (not tabular data) where `X` is the number of years passed and should be updated dynamically. Similar to insert the equivalent in the user's local currency at current exchange rate of a price mentioned in passing. (We use templates, albeit written in PHP, w/o curly intermediates, and have looked at Smarty etc., but found they would force us doing things their way, not ours.)

Comment: You can either have a degree of security, or you can have convenience. There's trade-offs here, but I'd advise caution. When you read about vulnerability reports, quite often it's a case of some well-intentioned feature being abused in ways that weren't anticipated by parties that weren't supposed to.